# NHibernate filter not applied on eagerly fetched child entities

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have a following data model:

```
Category
  Date
  Products

Product
  Date
  Payments

Payment
  Date
```

I wish to eager load the whole tree using NHibernate. I thought of doing it like that:

```
var query = from cat in session.Query<Category>() select cat;     
query = query.FetchMany(c => c.Products).ThenFetch(c=>c.Payments);     
var result = query.Distinct().ToList();
```

This works fine. It creates an left outer join and returns the results.

But I also only want to get entities that are newer than say 01/01/2012. So I created a filter called DateFilter and added the following to the Category, Product and Payment mapping:

```
ApplyFilter<DateFilter>();
```

When I enabled the filter, I expected the generated SQL query would have the filter conditions in "WHERE" clause for Category, Product and Payment tables but it only had the condition for Category (top element).

Code:

```
using (var session = SessionProvider.OpenSession(ConnectionString))
{
    session.EnableFilter("DateFilter")
        .SetParameter("start", OracleHelper.ToDate(new DateTime(2012, 1, 1)));

    var query = from cat in session.Query<Category>() select cat;     
    query = query.FetchMany(c => c.Products).ThenFetch(c=>c.Payments);     
    var result = query.Distinct().ToList();
}
```

Generated SQL:

```
SELECT ... FROM   ... WHERE category_.Date >= '2012-01-01'
```

And what I expected was:

```
SELECT ... FROM   ... WHERE category_.Date >= '2012-01-01' 
    and product_.Date >= '2012-01-01'
    and payment_.Date >= '2012-01-01'
```

I also tried applying the filter in the mapping like this:

```
HasMany<Payment>(x => x.Payments).ApplyFilter<DateFilter>();
```

But it applies the filter on the join (puts the filter conditions in the join's ON clause) not in the "WHERE" clause, which gives wrong results using left outer join.

Is filter only appliable on the top entity and not on eager-fetched child entities ?

How else could I achieve what I want to do ?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm certainly surprised by this, and it does't reflect how I remember this working. Can you confirm that the filter is working for `Products` generally (e.g. that a simple query for all products applies the filter)?

Comment: Yes, when just querying Payments or Products, the filters work. It just doesn't seem to work on child entities. Can anyone confirm this ?

Comment: Filters are available on collections see http://ayende.com/blog/3993/nhibernate-filters but not sure how to apply them using QueryOver